# Upgrading gearing help, currently running a 1x9 with a 30t crankset and 11/36t cassette. Can I upgrade to a 11-42t cassette?

Tags: derailleur, cassette, compatibility

I have a 1x9 that I really dislike and want to upgrade.  I was told to get a "Shimano Deore FC-M625 Double 2x10 Speed MTB Bike Crankset 38/24T" to upgrade my 1x.  I additionally caught a branch on a downed log and twisted my rear derailleur, so I bought new Shimano Alivio RD-MD3100-SGS due to the Acera being out of stock.

The specs say 36T max low sprocket, but I wondered if I added the Wolftooth Goatlink could I upgrade to a 11x42T cassette?

I see the total capacity states 45T, so if I calculate correctly the 38-24=14 and the 42-11=31 (14+31=45) then I should max out at the 45T capacity.  Am I on track with the increased cassette with this derailleur and the addition of the 2x crankset?

Comment: Hacks such as the Goat link belong to the past when wide range gears sets were very expensive. Have a look at microShift Advent if you want a cost effective 11-42  1x that works.

Comment: Keep in mind that a 9 speed setup with 11–42 cassette has very wide gear steps. Around ~20% for each step. I think a single chainring crankset with a 11–42 cassette (or similar) really only makes sense with at least 11 speeds in the rear.

Comment: I am going to move to a 2x crankset, I do not like the 1X and maybe your comment of needing an 11 speed makes more sense of why I do not like the 1x9.  I am looking to add a 38/24t crankset as soon I can get my hands on it, of course as you know components are not easily obtained right now.

Comment: Shimano do a 9 speed 36/22 crank.  That would give you the lower gear your want without the huge gaps associated with a 11-42 cassette.  36-11 is arguably a bit small as top gear, but I usually only spin mine out on steep road descents or with VERY strong tail winds.

Comment: Andy thanks for the suggestion.  I will look into that and make sure I can find that crank.  I have gotten out of shape and would be on the agreement the 36 is a bit small, so I am trying to find the balance that can help me keep up with a couple friends that will push me to keep moving and get back into shape.

Comment: @AndyP On a (presumably) MTB, 36/11 at 100rpm on a 29er is 45km/h. That’s plenty, unless you’re riding faster than that.

Comment: @Michael Depends on local terrain. If you have roadie or XC-style rolling terrain that requires smooth cadence shifts, that won’t work well. However, if you’re riding gravel road up, pure descent down type terrain, you really only need the bottom 2-3 and top 2-3 gears. The middle are just filler.

Comment: @AndyP  this is spot on.  The trail riding I am doing, I feel the top and bottom 2/3 gears are the needed gears with a 1X drivetrain, and without the large elevation or descents I am having quick changes that leave me frustrated with needing more time to get to the right gear. The 2x drivetrain will get me closer faster, and in turn some of the middle cassette may be more useful.  I see where the gradual/long climb/descent works with the 1x.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently running a RD-M3000 (which seem to match the specs of the RD-M3100) with a 11-42 cassette 9-speed (Advent). The original cassette was a 11/36.

So a few comments about this experience:

- no goatlink necessary
- to make it work, you have to adjust the B-screw, which means putting the derailleur cage further away from the cassette. Gear changes are less direct than before, especially on the small cogs (they were not specially direct before, that being said, it's the kind of things where you see a difference between Deore and Acera/Alivio).
- the design of the cage of the RD-M3000 is not ideal for that kind of use (it can have changed with the RD-M3100 though): the inside plate of the cage goes "above" the jockey wheel — this part usually finishes near the axle of the jockey wheel. It causes a problem for me in the combination big chainring/big sprocket: the cage get blocked by the sprocket, so I have to shift to the small chainring to escape this situation. It could be avoided by adjusting the b-screw, but the shifts will be less responsive. This problem may not happen if the gap between the chainrings is smaller than 16 teeth, that being said.

About your idea of going 2x, since it would imply to replace the drive train, a few comments to:

- make sure that you can pass a cable for the front derailleur and that your frame can accommodate a front derailleur (it's not always the case, especially with hydroformed tubes)
- the crankset that you mention is a 10-speed one. 9-speed chains are wider than 10-speed chains, so that might not be optimum
- Going 9-speed with an 11/42 cassette is going quite exotic (basically only Microshift if you want to stay as close as possible of the specs, but Microshift claims that Advent derailleurs require Advent shifters, so it adds another supply hurdle). If your constraint is more supply than budget, going to something more "mainstream" might be easier for you: for instance something like M5100 (11 speed, 1x11/51) or Shimano M4100 (2x10) might offer you more possibilities in term of supply without being too expensive.
- deriving from the comments: going 2x to have more "intermediate" steps is not necessary a good approach for me: if you think you miss a ratio between 2 cogs, and this speed is ratio is present using the other chainring, it will require you to know which combination it is and switch chainring and sprockets, which is never done in practice.
- check the clearance between the chain and the wheel, if you have large tires and not a boost axle: with a 2x, the chain will be a bit closer to the tire, better to make sure you can safely do it.

Comment: “deriving from the comments: going 2x to have more "intermediate" steps is not necessary a good approach for me” The thing is that with a 2x setup you can go for a normal 11–34 cassette which has much smaller steps than a 11–42 cassette.

Comment: It's right, but I would add that it depends also on the distribution of the sprockets. If I compare my previous 11/36 with the current 11/46, the difference is mostly noticeable in the largest sprockets, and less in the smaller ones — where differences are more noticeable  (11-13-15-17-20-23-26-30-36 vs 11-13-15-18-21-24-28-34-42).

Comment: Renaud, lots of good information to add to my learning curve of gearing.  I believe at this point I have read elsewhere and you also commented that 11/42 cassette will work with this derailleur, without the goatlink.  As far as the crankset, I did visit a bike shop and that was the recommended crankset by them.  I am liking this thread and communication, because once I started researching I wondered if this was his preference and  after @AndyP suggested a 36/22 crankset, I see where that gets me closer to what I feel the ratio I am looking for.  I am riding a 27.5" wheel DiamondBack Line.

Comment: @Renaud the front derailleur I was told by the local bike shop is a clamp band and designed for larger frames.  SHIMANO ALIVIO SIDE SWING Front Derailleur (Clamp Band) 2x9-speed  model FD-M3120-M-B

Comment: @JacobArmstrong Actually someone posted a picture of a RD-M3000 here https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77488/disassembly-of-shimano-acera-rd-m3000 and the one depicted in the picture doesn't have the same cage as mine and wouldn't have the problem mentioned in my third bullet.

Comment: The "B" in FD-M3120-M-B indeed indicates that it is for larger frames designs, with a "boost" rear axle (6mm larger than "standard" 135mm clearance). It would also require you to have a crankset sized for a "boost" rear axle (with the chainrings further from the center). But given the bike as a 135mm quick release, it's a gray zone for me. It might not be optimal because boost means 141mm of clearance for the rear wheel. But on the hand it might better to fit larger tires, but not for the frame. I would suggest to ask a new question if you have doubts.

Comment: I see the picture of the M3000 on the other post.  I want to say that looks just like the one I bent up, but due to difficult to find components right now, I was able to get the M3100, and they do look very similiar.  I have the SGS so its the longer cage.